# Cordova cannot find symbol error when build android project with self-built plugin (call for native java code)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I tried to run an android project in Cordova with self-build plugin,
Heres the code in JS and java for the plugin

```
var cordova = require('cordova');  

var Carrier = function() {};  

Carrier.prototype.getCarrierCode = function(success, error) {  
    cordova.exec(success, error, 'CarrierPlugin', 'getCarrierCode', []);  
};  

var carrier = new Carrier();  
module.exports = carrier;
```

this is the java code:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.provider.CallLog; 
import android.content.ContentResolver;
public class CarrierPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{
        public static final String TAG = "CarrierPlugin";  
        public static final String ACTION_GET_CARRIER_CODE = "getCarrierCode";  
        //public TelephonyManager tm;  
    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args,
        CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException{
        callbackContext.success("run it");
        return true;
    }

}
```

the error I got is "cannot find symbol :"
[image]

the strange thing is that, even if I change the code in the CarrierPlugin.java(delete the JSONException in line 16), it reported the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My Eclipse says, you should import CordovaInterface, CordovaWebView and CordovaArgs.

And you might be missing package declaration as well, depending wherever you want to put your plugin's java files, such as: 
`package com.yourdomain.etc` in the very first line of your Java file.

Comment: its not working, and the error is the same. I wondered if I run the project correctly, I changed the code in CarrierPlugin.java, then I run it with command"cordova run android".

Comment: and even if I change code in the java file. for example, I delete the JSONException, still it has error claiming cannot find symbol in line 16 "JSONException",

Comment: I am not good with command line, I use eclipse but you seem to have a problem with command line, don't forget to "cordova build" first. And just add some random characters here and there to make sure your modifications are built at all.

Comment: Ive tried to change the code, same error again.... I wondered if it really build the newest code